# Problems installing minimal Centos from DVD

Tags: centos

CentOS 8 is almost 7GB large and doesn't fit on a 4.7GB DVD. So I downloaded the boot.iso file and tried to install it.

During installation I need to select "Installation Source". I can enter select "closest mirror" or enter an http(s) or ftp URL.
"closest mirror" directly returns with the error message: "Error setting up base repository". 
I tried to enter the URL of a mirror für the full Centos 8 image, which is listed on the centos website. It says downloading package metadata. After waiting for 40 minutes I quit the installation. Of course I was connected to WiFi. 
How can I proceed with the installation of Centos 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully installed centos 8 using this source "http://mirror.myren.net.my/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/"

Try adjusting your mirror accordingly.

Refer below image for install screenshot.

[image]